# TSOA generates Typescript Pick, Partial and Omit schemas in swagger.json file

Tags: express, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, tsoa

I have been following the 'Getting started' [guide from TSOA](https://tsoa-community.github.io/docs/getting-started.html) to setup a new express project with typescript, add a nodemon configuration and swagger documentation. After finishing step three "Live reloading" the result should be a GET and POST route in swagger and two schemas: `User` and `UserCreationParams`.

I'm getting the same result except that it generated a third schema `Pick_User.email-or-name-or-phoneNumbers_`. If I create more routes and interfaces and create extra types using `Pick`, `Partial` or `Omit` they are all getting picked up and added to the schema.

I'm looking for a way to ignore these 'dirty' schemas

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to see how you declared these interfaces.

I'm working around this by declaring *nicely named* empty interfaces as aliases for the swagger documents, as follows...

```js
/* eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface */
export interface UserCreationParams extends Pick<User, 'email'|'name'|'phoneNumbers'> {}
```

A definition for `UserCreationParams` appears in the docs rather than the ugly auto-generated one from the Pick/Omit generic.

Our default linter setup complains about empty interfaces - so I have disabled that rule for all files defining the interfaces exposed to the swagger docs.

Comment: This is coming from the basic `Get started` guide from the TSOA website. 
`export type UserCreationParams = Pick<User, "email" | "name" | "phoneNumbers">;`

Comment: Yes, that does result in the 'ugly' entry in the swagger docs. If you change to an interface instead of a type it will use the interface name in the docs instead